# Mejor método para escribir en archivo con Ruby

Tags: ruby

Estoy usando ruby para (entre otras utilidades) descodificar archivos. Para ello, uso el siguiente método:

```
file = "file.dat"

xor_key = IO.binread(file, 4, 0).unpack("V*").join.to_i

save = File.new("decrypt.hdr", "wb")
save.write IO.binread(file, 4, 0)
to_xor = IO.binread(file, 4, 0).unpack("V*").join.to_i
for loop in 1..512-1
 seed = to_xor * 0x23451234
 bytes_to_decode = IO.binread(file, 4, loop * 4).unpack("V*").join.to_i
 save.write [(bytes_to_decode ^ to_xor).to_i.to_s(16).split(//).last(8).join.rjust(8, "0").scan(/(..)(..)(..)(..)/).map(&:reverse).join].pack("H*")
 to_xor = seed + (xor_key ^ 0xf0f0)
end
save.close
```

El caso es que si el archivo a desencriptar tiene muchos bytes, tarda un montón y con cada operación que hace dentro del loop tarda más.

Mi pregunta es si hay algún método alternativo para guardar los datos en un archivo o si se os ocurre alguna otra manera de simplificar el código.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una clase para mantener estado entre funciones y no repetir código. No sé si funcione de primera, pero espero te de una buena idea para refactorizar tu código.

```
class Decrypter
  attr_reader :input_file_name, :xor_key, :output_file, :to_xor
  attr_writer :to_xor

  def initialize(input_file_name, output_file_name)
    @input_file_name = input_file_name
    @xor_key         = binread_input(4, 0)
    @to_xor          = xor_key.dup
    @output_file     = File.new(output_file_name, "wb").tap do |f|
      f.write IO.binread(file, 4, 0)
    end
  end

  def run!
    for loop in 1..512-1
      seed = to_xor * 0x23451234
      bytes_to_decode = binread_input(4, loop * 4)
      write_to_output bytes_to_decode
      to_xor = seed + (xor_key ^ 0xf0f0)
    end
    output_file.close
  end

  def binread_input(length, offset)
    IO.binread(input_file_name, 4, 0).unpack("V*").join.to_i
  end

  def write_to_output(bytes)
    content = [(bytes ^ to_xor).to_i.to_s(16).split(//).last(8).join.rjust(8, "0").scan(/(..)(..)(..)(..)/).map(&:reverse).join].pack("H*")
    output_file.write(content)
  end
end
```

La usarías de la siguiente manera:

`Decrypter.new('file.dat', 'decrypt.hdr').run!`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar iteradores para hacer uso de fibras (threads pequeños) y me parece que deberías usar memoria si existe la posibilidad de contar con la cantidad suficiente y luego volcar a disco, es decir no escribir directo a disco en tu operacion.